# How to remove Child element of ul on double click?

Tags: javascript

```
var button = document.getElementById("enter");
var input = document.getElementById("userinput");
var ul = document.querySelector("ul");
var list=document.querySelectorAll("li")[0];



function inputLength(){
    return input.value.length;
}

function createListElement(){
    var li=document.createElement("li");
    li.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input.value));
    ul.appendChild(li);
    input.value="";
}

function addListAfterClick(){
    if (inputLength()>0){
        createListElement();
    }
}

function removeList(){
    ul.childNode.removeChild();
}



function addListAfterEnter(event){
    if(inputLength()>0 && event.keyCode==13){
         createListElement();
    }
}

button.addEventListener("click", addListAfterClick);
input.addEventListener("keypress", addListAfterEnter);
list.addEventListener("dblclick", removeList);
```

I am trying to create a shopping list, where I want to create a function, when I double click any

, that item should be removed, and add line-through on a single click.

**I am getting below error prompt in console log:**

dom-event.js:26 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'removeChild')
at HTMLLIElement.removeList

Comment: Please don't post images of code and provide more information what your code does.

Answer (score 0):

`Element.childNode` doesn't exist on HTML elements. However you have `Element.childNodes` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes) that returns a collection of all elements nested under the given `Element`.

In your case I suggest you'd use an event listener for each `li` and remove it when it's clicked (or doubleclicked).

Example :

```js
const l = document.getElementById("dynlist");

const items_data = ["some", "list", "items"];

function onListItemClick(event) {
    l.removeChild(event.target)
}

items_data.forEach(lidata => {
    const li = document.createElement("li");
    li.textContent = lidata;
    li.addEventListener("click", onListItemClick);
    l.appendChild(li);
})
```

```html
<ul id="dynlist">
</ul>
```

Comment: I tried this.. but same thing happening. Still not working

Comment: @Shahid I edited my answer providing an example snippet that you can run. You should be able to adapt this for your need. But maybe there are other problems in your code.